# Newly installed services not starting on boot

Tags: server, autostart

I've installed `sabnzbd` and I am able to run `service sabnzbdplus start` and `service sabnzbdplus stop` to start and stop the program without a problem. It has config files in `/etc/default` and `/etc/init.d`. I did notice that my plex server has an additional file in `/etc/init` and `sabnzbd` does not. I've learned a about the run levels, and the `rc2.d` folder also has a `S98sabnzbdplus` file. My run level is 2.

Here is the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a; apt-cache policy sabnzbdplus` :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
Linux Joshr 3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 201 5 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
sabnzbdplus:
Installed: 0.8.0~beta1-0ubuntu1~jcfp2~trusty
Candidate: 0.8.0~beta1-0ubuntu1~jcfp2~trusty
Version table:
*** 0.8.0~beta1-0ubuntu1~jcfp2~trusty 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jcfp/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 0.7.16-1ubuntu1 0
    500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

Here is the contents of the `/etc/default/sabnzbdplus` file:

```
# --daemon option is always used, and the program is
# started under the account of $USER, as set below.
#
# Each setting is marked either "required" or "optional";
# leaving any required setting unconfigured will cause
# the service to not start.

# [required] user or uid of account to run the program as:
USER=Joshr

# [optional] full path to the configuration file of your choice;
#            otherwise, the default location (in $USER's home
#            directory) is used:
CONFIG=

# [optional] hostname/ip and port number to listen on:
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=4000

# [optional] extra command line options, if any:
EXTRAOPTS=
```

Here is the output of the command `grep 'Joshr' /etc/passwd`

```
Joshr:x:1000:1000:Joshr,,,:/home/Joshr:/bin/bash
```

Yesterday I attempted adding the `service sabnzbdplus start` command to a script file, it worked fine when the script was manually executed. I then added a call to the script in the `/etc/rc.local` file, this still didn't work on startup.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `grep 'Joshr' /etc/passwd`